# SQL Server 2005 native stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, native

Can i write a C or native C++ stored procedures for SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - in SQL Server 2005 and up, you can write stored procs in managed code, e.g. C#, VB.NET etc.

For earlier SQL Server, there was the concept of extended stored procedures, which you could write in C or C++, and then plug into SQL Server and call it from there - but that capability is considered deprecated and potentially a security hole, so it's not recommended.

Here's a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mssqltutorial.aspx) on the topic that might be useful.

Marc